# tableView:indexPath* always returning a nil IndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uigesturerecognizer

I'm having some issues getting a long press gesture set up on table cells in an app I'm working on. I've tried three different configurations but haven't gotten one to work successfully yet.

Scenario 1)

I added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to my custom `UITableViewCell` class and was handling the action (showing an action sheet) inside an action that was part of the custom cell class. This worked but introduced the necessity to link the object the cell was rendering and then left me no way to update the tables data source (the action sheet is for removing items) so I abondoned this despite the `UIActionSheet` setup working fine.

Scenario 2)

Add the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the table view but handle it's action by the controller that contains the table view (I'm using a generic `UITableView`). In the action for the gesture recognizer I tried doing:

```
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];

    if (indexPath == nil)
        return;

    // Fetch item from index path and show action sheet
}
```

This was failing out at the test `if (indexPath == nil)`.

Scenario 3)

I found an example of adding a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on each cell when they're created and did so while still using the same handler in the controller containing the table view. I then changed the above test to:

```
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(MyCustomCell *)[sender view]];

    if (indexPath == nil)
        return;

    // Fetch item from index path and show action sheet
}
```

Again, this is continuously failing at the test `if (indexPath == nil)`.

Is there something I must do on a table view in order to fetch an index path or am I performing these checks in the wrong place? Is there a better method for adding a (preferably non-visible) means for showing a delete confirmation?

**EDIT**

Adding additional info in response to @Joel's comment.

Here is the view in question loaded in the simulator: http://grab.by/rHTA

To provide some visual information, the selected row in the view (3rd from the top) is the one I will be performing the long press gesture on for the context of the following logs.

```
2013-11-03 10:42:08.434 Application[35392:70b] Long press point = (143.000000, 168.000000)
2013-11-03 10:42:08.434 Application[35392:70b] IndexPath is nil
```

As you can see by the log `"IndexPath is nil"` which is printed only if `indexPath == nil` evaluates to true that the table view is not returning an index path for the point. The point is valid inside the tables frame.

This was performed with the same setup I listed for Scenario 2.

Comment: Your scenario 2 should work. What location are you getting back for `point`? Does this change if you capture it at UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded?

Comment: @Joel I would have thought so to, I updated the question with logs from Scenario 2 including the point that was calculated and the issue with IndexPath. I've also included a screenshot of the view in question.

Comment: I added your code (scenario 3) to the action handler for a long press gesture recognizer (added to each cell), and it worked fine. Can you show how you're adding the gesture recognizer, and the complete handler method?

Comment: @rdelmar Please check out my answer, I've solved my own issue and it was something extremely minor that I should have been double checking the whole time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making this an answer because it's resolved my problem.

I apologize for stringing everyone on with this question but it turns out the core issue was a failure to link the table view to it's `IBOutlet` in the view controller which I originally did but must of have accidentally removed when trying to implement this long press issue.

Adding the link back to the view controller so that `self.tableView` was no longer `nil` itself I began getting accurate results.

I apologize for failing to verify simple things like this before and will be mindful of them in the future. Thanks to @Joel and @rdelmar for attempting to get me on the right track but as you both said, each scenario *should work* (and does) so long as everything else is set up accordingly.